# For react app vith vite, in development, reloading does not work

Tags: reactjs, vite, reload, i18next

I am new to vite. I convert my cra projects to vite and I have problems in localhost when I make changes in my code : the application crashes (not systematically but often).

Here are the console errors :

> Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.

> Uncaught DOMException: Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node

> The above error occurred in the  component:
>
> recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects@http://localhost:3004/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-CKWPCP4A.js?v=4c7ec087:17681:43
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries.

No matter how much I search, I don't understand where it comes from. I had no problem with CRA.

Has anyone ever had the problem? Do you know where it comes from?
I can post other files if needed

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example please.